# Ag-grid cell renderer doesn't update its rowIndex in real time?

Tags: ag-grid

I'm wondering how I can complete my cell renderer. The renderer adds a new row when clicking an icon, and removes it when clicked again. The problem is the invididual cell renderers row indexes do not change unless I hard refresh the entire grid (which then disables the state of the dropdown itself)

How can I complete this?

```
const insertIndex = params.rowIndex + 1;

            this.eventListener = () => {
                if (!this.eButton.classList.contains('open')) {
                    gridOptions.api.applyTransaction({add:[{step: this.dropdownValue, dropdownRow: true}], addIndex: insertIndex });
                } else {
                    let rowData = [];
                    gridOptions.api.forEachNode(function (node) {
                        rowData.push(node);
                    });

                    let insertedRow = rowData[insertIndex];
                    gridOptions.api.applyTransaction({remove:[insertedRow.data]});
                }

                this.eButton.classList.toggle('open');
            };

            this.eButton.addEventListener('click', this.eventListener);
        }
```

option 1: Hard refresh the grid, but I lose the 'open' status of the dropdown icon. How can i carry state over after a hard refresh?

option 2: Find a way that params.rowIndex is updated after applyTransaction.

Ive tried using the default rowGroup feature, however it hides all columns by default and I havent found a way to make it work the way I need.

The solution im after is a simple 'open/close' toggle for a single row underneath without affecting the other rows